# Excel to Dynamically Insert Fields

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic

I have an Excel spreadsheet devoted to monitoring flags and other variables on a device and they are displayed as follows and are dynamically updated:

```
Flag name    TimeStamp    Value
SomeFlag     05:45:12     0
SomeOther    08:22:23     1
Another      08:22:23     0
```

I have another spreadsheet where I provide an overview of all the devices being monitored. On this spreadsheet, I would like to only display flags that have the value of 1 on the devoted spreadsheets. So for the example above, it would look as follows:

```
Voltage    09:22:45    230V
Current    09:22:45    15A
Flags:     SomeOther   1
```

If more flags were to become 1, they must be added dynamically. For example, if the Another flag becomes 1, the overview would look as follows:

```
Voltage    09:22:46    230V
Current    09:22:46    15A
Flags:     SomeOther   1
           Another     1
```

Can someone assist me? I know how to use VBA, but I need some guidance in getting started with this.

Comment: Voltage and current where does this come from and is this the same for the first two rows of the output or does this need to be displayed before every flag?

Comment: I import the data using PI Datalink, a connector to a data historian. Voltage and Current must **not** appear before every flag. It only appears once at the top. The flags appear underneath one another.

Comment: to import the volt/current is this something that the VBA must handle?

Comment: No. Everything is imported using PI Datalink. I want to insert a value from another spreadsheet the the overview sheet when that value (the flag) becomes 1, and remove it from the overview sheet when the value becomes 0.

Answer (score 0):

The below will read the data into an array

```
Sub t()
Dim arr()
ReDim arr(1)
i = 0

With ActiveSheet
    lastrow = .Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
    For Each cell In Range("A2:A" & lastrow)
        If cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = 1 Then
            arr(i) = cell.Value
            arr(i + 1) = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
            ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) + 2)
            i = i + 2
        End If
    Next
End With

For i = 0 To UBound(arr()) - 2 Step 2
    Debug.Print arr(i) & ":" & arr(i + 1)
    'change debug.print to the range/sheet etc of where you would like the output to start
    'may need to clean output range first
Next
End Sub
```

the output is currently only outputting to the immediate window so that will need to be changed but should be enough to get you going. Remember to step 2 when outputting array as you are putting 2 values per iteration